# xamarin.forms hamburger icon

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, hamburger-menu

I have a problem with master page and hamburger button, when the menu is hidden the height of the button doesn't fill the height (first image), othervise yes (second image). I really don't understand.
Somebody can help me?

[image: menu closed]

[image: menu expaned]

Thanks a lot in advance.

here the page to show

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DMInfoOrganizer"
         x:Class="DMInfoOrganizer.Impostazioni" Title="{local:Translate TxtImpostazioni}" >
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="Lbl" Text="{local:Translate TxtImpostazioni}"            
          VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

here the masterpage

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DMInfoOrganizer"
             x:Class="DMInfoOrganizer.MasterPage">
        <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="lstMenu" x:FieldModifier="public">
                <ListView.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:MasterPageItem}">
                    <local:MasterPageItem Title="{local:Translate TxtHome}" TargetType="{x:Type local:Home}" />
                    <local:MasterPageItem Title="{local:Translate TxtNuovaLibreria}" TargetType="{x:Type local:NuovaLibreria}" />
                    <local:MasterPageItem Title="{local:Translate TxtImpostazioni}" TargetType="{x:Type local:Impostazioni}" />
                </x:Array>
                </ListView.ItemsSource>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Padding="5,10">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell Microsoft has changed the toolbar items height in 1809 and your app doesn't seem to handle that well. So you shouldn't use SDK for 1809 to compile the app (but some older) and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot!

The problem is that I can't compile app with older sdk version because I have this error

```
This version of Win2D requires Windows SDK >= 10.0.17134.0, but TargetPlatformVersion is 10.0.16299.0.
```

edit: I Installed the 10.0.17134.0 version and now all works.